# what is the benefit of adding UserClaims 'role' to IdentityResource

Tags: identityserver4

why we add , or what the benefit of adding UserClaims 'role' to IdentityResource

```
new IdentityResource { Name = "role", UserClaims = new List<string> {"role"} }
```

it's not add the roles to the token

i can only add the roles to token by adding UserClaims 'role' to ApiResource

when i remove UserClaims 'role' from IdentityResource my project also work fine.

Answer (score 2):

The `'UserClaims'` that are identified would be required for a user to have in their identity token when they try to use the particular resource.

If this resource was an API and you had the UserClaim `'Admin'` defined.

```
new IdentityResource { 
           Name = "MyAPI", UserClaims = new List<string> {"Admin"} 
}
```

The API methods would not be able to be used unless the user had the `'Admin'` claim.

[IdentityServer4 Documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/resources.html).

**UPDATE:**

`JwtClaimTypes.Role` is a common claim type or group. I don't think it would be common to have a claim value of `'role'` in the claims type of `JwtClaimTypes.Role`.

See the following example: ([Source](https://github.com/damienbod/AspNet5IdentityServerAngularImplicitFlow/blob/master/src/IdentityServerWithIdentitySQLite/IdentityWithAdditionalClaimsProfileService.cs))

```
        var claims = principal.Claims.ToList();

        claims = claims.Where(claim => context.RequestedClaimTypes.Contains(claim.Type)).ToList();


        claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.GivenName, user.UserName));
        //new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "admin"),
        //new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "dataEventRecords.admin"),
        //new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "dataEventRecords.user"),
        //new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "dataEventRecords"),
        //new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "securedFiles.user"),
        //new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "securedFiles.admin"),
        //new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "securedFiles")

        if (user.IsAdmin)
        {
            claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "admin"));
        }
        else
        {
            claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "user"));
        }

        if (user.DataEventRecordsRole == "dataEventRecords.admin")
        {
            claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "dataEventRecords.admin"));
            claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "dataEventRecords.user"));
            claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "dataEventRecords"));
            claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Scope, "dataEventRecords"));
        }
        else
        {
            claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "dataEventRecords.user"));
            claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "dataEventRecords"));
            claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Scope, "dataEventRecords"));
        }
```

Comment: thanks  @aaronR,  but i ask about 'role'  Specifically , 
why we put  JwtClaimTypes.Role  in IdentityResource like that

 new IdentityResource
                                {
                                   Name = "roles",
                                   UserClaims = { JwtClaimTypes.Role }
                                }

Comment: many thanks @aaronR,  
in your project example , in config.cs file :


                new IdentityResource("dataeventrecordsscope",new []{ "role", "admin", "user", …..

what  ‘role’ do here ?
in the same file in ApiResource we added ‘role’ to include it with token
but why we put it in IdentityResource also

Comment: FYI: That is not my own code. Let me see if I can answer that for you.